# How to access windows drive data in ubuntu on a dual boot machine?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I have a dual boot machine with Windows 8 and Ubuntu. I have lots of data on my Windows C drive (images/songs/videos), which I am not able to locate/ access through Ubuntu.

Is it possible to get the data in Ubuntu? If yes, how?

Comment: Next time, you would be better off asking on *Ask Ubuntu* (or on *Super User*).

Answer (score 0):

You can mount NTFS partitions with the `ntfs-3g` driver. You should be able to mount it on demand from Nautilus, like this:

[image: Nautilus mount partition]

The other solution would be adding a custom entry in `/etc/fstab`, so it will be mounted automatically during the boot process. This [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions) can help you. An example: let's assume your Windows partition is the first partion, on the first disk (a.k.a. /dev/sda1). In this case, the `fstab` entry for `rw` access would be similar:

```
/dev/sda1  /media/Windows  ntfs  defaults,umask=000  0  0
```